# Terraform: aws_elb.terraformelb: : invalid or unknown key: subnet_id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, terraform

I'm trying to assign an ELB to a public subnet that's within a new VPC:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.dev-vpc.id}"
  cidr_block = "${var.public_subnet}"
  availability_zone = "${var.aws_region}a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags {
    Name = "public"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
    aws_elb.terraformelb: : invalid or unknown key: subnet_id
```

If I remove the subnet parameter, the ELB is assigned to a default VPC.

Here's my terraform elb code:

```
    resource "aws_elb" "terraformelb" {
        subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.public.id}"
        security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.terraformelb-sg.id}"]
        cross_zone_load_balancing = "true"
        idle_timeout = "60"
        connection_draining = "true"
        connection_draining_timeout = "300"
        tags = {
              Name = "${var.environment}-${var.environment_name}-elb"
              Env_Name = "${var.environment}-${var.environment_name}"
              Environment = "${var.environment}"
              Version = "${var.version}"
        }
        listener {
          lb_port           = 80
          lb_protocol       = "http"
          instance_port     = "${var.server_port}"
          instance_protocol = "http"
        }

        health_check {
          healthy_threshold = "10"
          unhealthy_threshold = "2"
          timeout = "2"
          interval = "5"
          target = "HTTP:${var.server_port}/"
        }
    }
```

Please let me know how to assign an ELB to a subnet.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

it's **subnets** instead of  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.public.id}"

Answer (score 0):

Subnets is the parameter you want.

> subnets - (Required for a VPC ELB) A list of subnet IDs to attach to
>   the ELB.

```
 subnets = ["${aws_subnet.public.id}"]
```

Also availability_zones is not required for VPC ELB's, it's implied with the subnet provided.

> availability_zones - (Required for an EC2-classic ELB) The AZ's to
>   serve traffic in.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elb.html#subnets

It may be a good idea to also provision several more public subnets in different AZ's, if you are setting `cross_zone_load_balancing` to "true"

> Create a subnet in each Availability Zone where you want to launch
>   instances. Depending on your application, you can launch your
>   instances in public subnets, private subnets, or a combination of
>   public and private subnets. A public subnet has a route to an Internet
>   gateway. Note that default VPCs have one public subnet per
>   Availability Zone by default.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-backend-instances.html